# pybind11 - Segmentation Fault on `import` when using `py::object`

Tags: segmentation-fault, pybind11

I am trying to create a class in C++ that I will expose to Python 3.6 using pybind11.  I installed pybind11 using `sudo pip install "pybind11[global]"` (I am on Ubuntu), and got some simple programs to work.  However, I tried to use pybind11's wrappers for C++ objects, as shown [here](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/functions.html#python-objects-as-arguments), and things went wrong.  If my class so much as mentions `py::object` in an exposed function, it does still compile successfully, but I get a Segmentation Fault (core dumped) when I try to `import` the module in Python.

I tried using `python3.6 -v -c "import [module]"` and seemed to get the same error as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525460/error-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-when-import-module-built-from-pybind11) post.  I added `

I recreated the problem in these simpler toy files.  Here are the files that contain the C++ class.

toy.hpp

```cpp
#ifndef TOY
#define TOY
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

class Toy
{
    public: 
        Toy();
        int pure_cpp(int x);
        int uses_pybind11(py::object obj);
};

#endif
```

toy.cpp

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <toy.hpp>

namespace py = pybind11;

int Toy::pure_cpp(int x)
{
    return 24;
}
int Toy::uses_pybind11(py::object obj)
{
    return 25;
}
```

Here is the file which creates the module using a pybind11 macro.

toy_binding.cpp

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <toy.hpp>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(toybox, m)
{
    py::class_<Toy>(m, "Toy")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("pure_cpp", &Toy::pure_cpp)
        .def("uses_pybind11", &Toy::uses_pybind11)
        ;
}
```

Here are the compile strings I use.

```sh
g++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++14 -fPIC \
    toy.cpp \
    -o libtoy.so \
    -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/usr/local/include/python3.6 -I/home/user/.local/include/python3.6m \
    -I. \

g++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++14 -fPIC \
    toy_binding.cpp \
    -o toybox.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so \
    -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/usr/local/include/python3.6 -I/home/user/.local/include/python3.6m \
    -I. -I/usr/include/python3.6 \
    -L. -ltoy -Wl,-rpath,. \
    -lpcap
```

(Yes, I know it should be a makefile, but I thought this would be quick)

**Note** that if I remove `.def("uses_pybind11", &Toy::uses_pybind11)` from the module-building macro, everything works perfectly fine.  `uses_pybind11` doesn't even *use* the `py::object`; it just has it as a parameter.  The moment I try to do `import toybox` in Python 3.6, I immediately get kicked out with a Segmentation Fault.

The docs didn't seem to indicate that I had to do anything special to get `py::object` etc. to work.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: For future reference, this occured on pybind11 version 2.6.2

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  For whatever reason, I had to either a) implement any functions that use `py::object` directly in `toy.hpp`; or b) also `include` the `toy.cpp` file in `toy_binder.cpp`, the file which we will turn into the Python module.

In other words, changing `toy_binder.cpp` to the following is sufficient.

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <toy.hpp>
#include <toy.cpp> // <-------- ADD THIS 

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(toybox, m)
{
    py::class_<Toy>(m, "Toy")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("pure_cpp", &Toy::pure_cpp)
        .def("uses_pybind11", &Toy::uses_pybind11)
        ;
}
```

I discovered this fix by switching to Python 3.8, which, for some reason, gives the following helpful error when I try to `import toybox`, instead of just throwing a Segmentation Fault.

```
ImportError: /home/user/Desktop/Mechaform/mechaform/evangelion/magi/toybox.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3Toy13uses_pybind11EN8pybind116objectE
```

De-mangling that string shows that the undefined symbol is `Toy::uses_pybind11(pybind11::object)`.  Huh?  Why is this undefined, when I *did* define it in `toy.cpp`?  I should also point out that I don't get this issue when I try to compile with the `pure_cpp` function alone.

Does anyone know what the issue is here?  My hypothesis is some kind of linker error, perhaps.

Comment: The Python 3.8 error message tip was very helpful! On 3.6, I too was only seeing a Seg Fault, but now I see a explicit undefined symbol message after upgrading.